# Marshalling via WebServiceGatewaySupport fails with JAXBException: class <classname> nor any of its super class is known to this context

Tags: jaxb, webservice-client

I want to call webservices via clients. The clients are instantiated as beans:

```
@Configuration
public class ServiceClientConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setContextPath(CONTEXT_PATH);
        return marshaller;
    }

    @Bean
    public Service1Client authenticate(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
        Service1Client client = new Service1Client();
        client.setDefaultUri("http://localhost:8292/service1");
        client.setMarshaller(marshaller);
        client.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
        return client;
    }

    @Bean
    public Service2Client broker(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
        Service2Client client = new Service2Client();
        client.setDefaultUri("http://localhost:8192/service2");
        client.setMarshaller(marshaller);
        client.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
        return client;
    }
```

Though the both of the services are different, the request and responses are defined via xsd-files to the same package name - which is provided here as String 'CONTEXT_PATH' to  the marshaller.

The clients itself look like this:

```
public class Service1Client extends WebServiceGatewaySupport { 
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Tools.getClassName());

    public Service1Response process(Service1Request request) {

        Service1Response response = null;
        try {
            response = (Service1Response) getWebServiceTemplate()
                .marshalSendAndReceive("http://localhost:8292/service1", request);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("", e);
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Service2Client extends WebServiceGatewaySupport { 
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Tools.getClassName());

    public Service2Response process(Service2Request request) {

        Service2Response response = null;
        try {
            response = (Service2Response) getWebServiceTemplate()
                .marshalSendAndReceive("http://localhost:8192/service2", request);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("", e);
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

While running Service1Client is fine, the Service2Client fails with

```
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class <package>.Service2Request nor any of its super class is known to this context.
```

I removed "Service1Client" from the code - but the error remained to be the same.

Comment: When setting up the jaxbMarshaller with:
marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(Service1Request.class, Service2Request..class); 
instead of
 marshaller.setContextPath(CONTEXT_PATH);
it seems to work.
I'm happy I found something to get it run - but I'm king of confused. The contextPath has for me the idea to register all of the classes. I would prefer this over being forced to name all classes explicitely.

Answer (score 0):

I have renamed the pathname of the CONTEXT_PATH. It was "types.". I changed it to "dto.". Now it works as expected.
For me the reason for the problem looks sort of strange - maybe somebody can explain it.